# Tapestry, Zone inside loop

Tags: java, apache, tapestry

I have another big issue. I have component, with zone, and form that refreshes the zone. When I put component inside loop, it shows only last zone. I generated unique ID for every zone. In page source, I can see that every zone get's right ID, but it doesn't return right on submit. Is there anyway to return zone by id?

Here is my code:

```xml
<details>      
    <summary>Comments</summary><br />        
      <t:zone t:id="commentZone" id="prop:zoneId">                
                <t:commentlist materijalID="materijalID"></t:commentlist><br />  
    </t:zone>                
    <t:form t:id="komentar" t:context="materijalID" t:zone="prop:zoneId">
            <t:textarea t:value="comment" rows="6" cols="40"></t:textarea><br />
             <input type="submit" value="Add comment"/>
    </t:form>
</details>
```

```java
public class Comments 
{   
    @Parameter(required=true) 
    @Property 
    private int materijalID; 

    @SessionState 
    @Property 
    private User user; 

    @Inject 
    private Session session; 

    @Property 
    private String comment; 

    @InjectComponent 
    private Zone commentZone; 


    @CommitAfter 
    public Object onSuccessFromKomentar(int materijalID) 
    {
        Komentar k = new Komentar(); 
        Date d = new Date(); 
        Materijal m = (Materijal)session
                .createCriteria(Materijal.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("materijalID", materijalID))
                .list()
                .get(0); 
        k.setMaterijal(m); 
        k.setKorisnikID(this.user.getID()); 
        k.setDatumUnosa(d); 
        k.setDatumModifikacije(d); 
        k.setKomentar(this.comment); 
        session.save(k); 
        this.comment = ""; 
        return this.commentZone.getBody(); 
    }

    public String getZoneId() 
    { 
        return "Zone_" + this.materijalID; 
    } 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `t:defer="false"` in the `Submit`?

Henning answers a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6014623)

Answer (score 0):

The problem will most likely be that the materijalID you pass into your commentList is the same as is passed in as a @Parameter. Meaning your encapsulating component will set this value for you. In the case of your loop this is most likely always the last one after your render phase.

The solution lies in decoupling this passthough. Something along the lines of:

```xml
<details>      
    <summary>Comments</summary><br />        
    <t:zone t:id="commentZone" id="prop:zoneId">                
        <t:commentlist materijalID="prop:passThroughMaterijalID"></t:commentlist>
        <br />  
    </t:zone>                
    <t:form t:id="komentar" t:context="materijalID" t:zone="prop:zoneId">
        <t:textarea t:value="comment" rows="6" cols="40"></t:textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add comment"/>
    </t:form>
</details>
```

```java
public class Comments 
{   
    @Parameter(required=true) 
    @Property 
    private int materijalID; 

    @Property 
    private int passThroughMaterijalID; 

    @SessionState 
    @Property 
    private User user; 

    @Inject 
    private Session session; 

    @Property 
    private String comment; 

    @InjectComponent 
    private Zone commentZone; 

    @SetupRender
    private void setup() {
        this.passThroughMaterijalID = materijalID;
    }


    @CommitAfter 
    public Object onSuccessFromKomentar(int materijalID) 
    {   
        this.passThroughMaterijalID = materijalID;
        Komentar k = new Komentar(); 
        Date d = new Date(); 
        Materijal m = (Materijal)session
                .createCriteria(Materijal.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("materijalID", materijalID))
                .list()
                .get(0); 
        k.setMaterijal(m); 
        k.setKorisnikID(this.user.getID()); 
        k.setDatumUnosa(d); 
        k.setDatumModifikacije(d); 
        k.setKomentar(this.comment); 
        session.save(k); 
        this.comment = ""; 
        return this.commentZone.getBody(); 
    } 

    public String getZoneId() 
    { 
            return "Zone_" + this.materijalID; 
    } 
}
```